# Join cells from Pandas data frame and safe as one string or .txt file

Tags: pandas, string, dataframe

I am trying to extract data from a data frame in Pandas and merge the results into one string (or .txt file)

Data Frame:

|  | NUM | LETTER |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 4 | Z |
| 1 | 5 | U |
| 2 | 6 | A |
| 3 | 7 | P |
| 4 | 1 | B |
| 5 | 4 | P |
| 6 | 5 | L |
| 7 | 6 | T |
| 8 | 7 | V |
| 9 | 1 | E |

**Script so far:**

```py
data = pd.read_csv("TEST.csv")
fdata = data[data["LETTER"].str.contains("A|E|L|P")]
ffdata = fdata.RESULT.to_string()
print(ffdata)
```

Running the script on TEST.csv gives me this result:

|  | LETTER |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | A |
| 3 | P |
| 5 | P |
| 6 | L |
| 9 | E |

Next, I want to join the data from the filtered cells and join them into one string:

--> "APPLE", optional with saving them as .txt to use them later.

How do I proceed from here? I was thinking about iterating over the data frame and use join, but I have no idea how to implement this. Any clues?

Comment: `"".join(fdata.LETTER.to_list())`

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Frodnar's answer, this is the code that works:

```
data = pd.read_csv("TEST.csv")
fdata = data[data["LETTER"].str.contains("A|E|L|P")]
ffdata = ''.join(fdata.LETTER.to_list())
print(ffdata)
```

which gives the output 'APPLE'

Thank you for your help!!